# Hadith: Blood of Muslim is more sacred then the Kaabah?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

The blood of a Muslim is more scared then the Kaabah is this hadith authentic?

In the Targhib wa’ l-Tarhib of Imam al-Mundhiri, 3/276 it has the following hadith from `Abd Allah ibn`Amr ibn al-`As (Allah be well pleased with him) that he said:

“I saw the Messenger of Allah (saw) performing tawaf around the Holy Ka`ba saying to it: ‘how pure and good you are! how pure and good your fragrance is! how great and exalted you are! and how great and exalted your sanctity is! But by Him in Whose hand is Muhammad’s soul, the sanctity of a believer’s blood and property in the sight of Allah is greater than your sanctity!’“

رأيت رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يطوف بالكعبة ويقول ما أطيبك وما أطيب ريحك ما أعظمك وما أعظم حرمتك والذي نفس محمد بيده لحرمه المؤمن عند الله أعظم من حرمتك ماله ودمه

Answer (score 1):

The source is a da'if hadith compiled by ibn Majah in his [sunan](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/7). It can also be found in several books of at-Tabarani like his al-Mo'jam al-Kabir all with weak narrators in the chain.

It was also quoted as a statement of ibn 'Omar in jami' [at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/27/138):

> He (Nafl’) said: ‘ One day Ibn ‘Umar looked at the House- or – the Ka’bah and said: ‘What is it that is more honored than you, and whose honor is more sacred than yours! And the believer’s honor is more sacred to Allah than yours.’”

And al-Bayhaqi البيهقي in his sho'ab al-Emaan شعب الإيمان quoted a similar wording twice one of them on the authority of abi Hazem:

> لما نظر رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وسلم - إلى الكعبة قال: - صلى الله عليه وسلم - إلى الكعبة قال: مرحباً بكِ من بيتٍ، ما أعظمَكِ، وأعظمَ حرمَتَكِ! وللمؤمنُ أعظمُ حرمةً عند اللهِ منكِ، إن اللهَ حرّم منكِ واحدةَّ، وحرّمَ مِنَ المؤمنِ ثلاثاً: دمَه، ومالَه، وأن يُظَنَّ به ظنُّ السُّوءِ

The other on the authority of ibn 'Abbas:

> لما نظر رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وسلم - إلى الكعبة قال: ما أعظمَ حرمَتَكِ! وللمؤمنُ أعظمُ حرمةً عند اللهِ منكِ، إن اللهَ حرّم منكِ واحدةَّ، وحرّمَ مِنَ المؤمنِ ثلاثاً: دمَه، ومالَه، وأن يُظَنَّ به ظنُّ السُّوءِ

These two last sources have at least reached the degree of hassan as both include  mostly narrators who are in the both sahih books.

See also [this thread](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=277993) in Arabic.